# how to click on drawableRight on every TextInputEditText

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, android-textinputedittext

[image]

how to do click on drawableRight edit image of every TextInputEditText? I want to click on the edit icon and then enable to edit each field. How can i do this?

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--First name-->

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_64dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                   
                    android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_edit"
                    android:hint="@string/label_fname"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <!--Middle name-->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_registration_tiMiddleName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_64dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMiddleName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_edit"
                    android:hint="@string/label_mname"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


     </LinearLayout>
```

so how to each field individually edit using drawbleRight. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `android:drawableRight` in the `TextInputEditText`.
Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
```

and:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener {
  // Respond to end icon presses
}
```

Comment: This is perfect solution. Thanks a lot @ Mr. Gabrele Mariotti

Comment: @ Gabriele Mariotti   can you help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789319/how-to-change-visiblity-visible-invisible-or-gone-of-setendicondrawable-in-t        in this problem  as it is related to this answer you helped me.