# How to change visiblity (visible, invisible or gone ) of setEndIconDrawable in TextInputLayout android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

[image]

I am trying to make invisible or visibility gone of endIconDrawable which is the edit icon in the picture above for FirstName field only and want to keep visibile edit icon rest of the fields but unable to do? How can i do this?

```
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_64dp"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icon_edit"
                app:endIconMode="custom">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:hint="@string/label_fname"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I wanted to get the following as shown in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it in the layout (static way) just don't add the `app:endIconDrawable`/`app:endIconMode` attributes:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_64dp">
```

Programmatically to remove the `endIconDrawable` you can use:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE);
```

To add the `endIconDrawable` you can use:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM);
textInputLayout.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.xxxx);
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried @Gabriele Mariotti 's answer. It's good but it has a problem. I used the code for making endicon visible or invisible in text watcher and it didn't work as desired. Then I used **isEndIconVisible** attribute for **textInputLayout** and maje it true or false. It works correctly as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 KOTLIN**

best solution:

```
textInputLayout.isEndIconVisible = false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below steps inside this `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
app:endIconMode="custom"
app:endIconCheckable="false"
app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/sv_password_hide"
```

**Full code**

```js
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="320dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtlay"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/card_view_bg"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/input_Field_stroke"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth=".5dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconCheckable="false"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/sv_password_hide" 
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/input_hint">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/inpCurPass"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                        android:hint="@string/current_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**And in kotlin file (activity/fragment)**

```js
mBind.txtlay.setEndIconOnClickListener {
            val s = mBind.txtlay.isEndIconCheckable
            mBind.txtlay.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM)
            if (s) {
                mBind.txtlay.isEndIconCheckable = false
                mBind.txtlay.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.sv_password_hide)
                mBind.inpCurPass.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
            } else {
                mBind.txtlay.isEndIconCheckable = true
                mBind.txtlay.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.sv_password_show)
                mBind.inpCurPass.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -5):

Add this `android:visibility="gone"`